# Styling custom panelmenu label

Tags: angular, primeng

I have code below

```
this.menu=[
  {
    label: LabelGenerator.getLabelHTML('Home', false),
    escape:false
  }
];
```

---

```
export class LabelGenerator{
  static getLabelHTML(name: string, showArrow: boolean): string{
    return `<div class="p-d-flex p-ai-center sideMenuListTitle">
      <div>
        <span>2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="p-ml-2">${name}</div>
        <div></div>
      </div>`;
  }
}
```

---

```
    .sideMenuListTitle span{
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #616161;
}
```

The problem is that `.sideMenuListTitle span` styles dont apply to my label.

If I include this styles directly in getLabelHTML then Angular says `sanitizing HTML stripped some content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When styling dynamic HTML in your component you need to consider [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation) . Easiest solution its move your styles to global styles (styles.scss if you use SASS) or wrap your styles with ng-deep in component styles :

```
::ng-deep {
  pass your styles here
}
```